# I'm having trouble getting my jQuery to work on the simplest level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

Ok, so this is a total noob question. I'm trying to build a site from scratch using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and I want to use jQuery. For some reason I can get the HTML and CSS working but I can't use jQuery in my `script.js` file. I've downloaded jQuery:

[image]

And I've linked to it with a `<script>` tag, but when I try to use what I've built, nothing happens.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Freeflow Academy</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' />

        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
p {    
    background-color: blue;
}
```

My JavaScript with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('p').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');    
    });    
});
```

All I'm trying to do is get the background color to change on a click. Any help is appreciated. I think the problem has to do with my `<script>` or `<link>` tags, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I'll check. OK:   `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` and `SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0001'`

Comment: ok..the first error is because of the incorrect order of loading the scripts..now, for the second error, could you please tell the line number of the error or else reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)..

Comment: always check errors first...then ask questions and include error details

Comment: What charset can I use to get rid of the second error? It refers to the very first line of the `jQuery-2.2.0.min.js`. There's an unrecognized character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First load jQuery, then your custom script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

The loading priority is from top to bottom, if jQuery is not loaded before script loads, it won't work.

Comment: Hmmm. Nothing changed. Still getting the same errors in the console.

Comment: Can you give a demo URL? @KaiChristensen

Comment: I'll see if I can get a fiddle running.

Answer (score 0):

Order is not correct, first load jquery and then script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm. Nothing changed. Still getting the same errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you're loading your custom JavaScript before you're loading jQuery.

*load-order*

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Also, but un-related to JavaScript errors is your ordering of stylesheets and the `type` attribute value you are using, which should be `type="text/css"`.

I created a working example on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xodoyof/edit?html,css,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning charset for script tags with correct order of tags.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' charset="UTF-8" src='script.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Freeflow Academy</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test</p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

First of all, a best practice is to load your scripts (jquery, your custom scripts and so on) at the end of the file. Also, I will go for a CDN. You can find few reasons why to do this [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/) (just google it).

The quotes, single or double, depends just by your style. I m going for double, but just keep them everywhere in a single way, keep your code clean :D.

The single reason that could be, despite the `script` order from your post, is your Apache settings. Maybe the relative paths and directory root are not the correct ones. You can have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/532630/is-the-apache-directory-directive-supposed-to-be-relative-to-the-documentroot-or)

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, the loading order is important.
Also it's a good idea to load jquery from their cdn like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Also to make sure all external resources are loaded with the right protocol (e.g. http or https) strip of the `http:` part in the `href=` :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='stylesheet' href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
```

Should you still get the error after updating your code, try clearing your browser cache.